# Share Home Directory between Arch and Windows

Tags: arch-linux, partition, windows, dual-boot

Would it be possible to share the home directory between Arch and Windows with both installed on the same device? With encryption?

Answer (score 1):

Linux and Windows home directories are quite different, so sharing them may not be in your best interest. But you can share a directory dedicated for this purpose by using a filesystem readable by both operating systems, such as FAT32 or NTFS. For encryption you can use VeraCrypt.